# How to prevent stopping SQL Server instance after a while?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have SQL Server 2014 Express installed in a firm with my C# application. Every once in a while, when the app isn't used for some time, the SQL Server instance stops. And I have to go there, enter the services and manually start it. After that it works just fine.

How can I prevent this?

I have set the startup type for my SQL Server service to Automatic.

Should I maybe try to set it to `Automatic(delayed start)`?

The machine that the SQL Server is installed on is running Microsoft Server 2012.
And for now it is not connected to the internet, it's only in LAN.

So I guess the thing with the updates is not the problem, because the machine is not on the internet.

This is the exception that is thrown:

[image]

Comment: That exception is thrown when trying to connect to your instance. You need to understand why it is shutting down. Most likely an exception of some sort.

Comment: Delayed start will just delay the startup of the service when the machine boots. That's not going to help much or at all. Definitely troubleshoot the root cause of the service stopping.

Comment: I know why it is shutting down. It's because my SQL Server service instance is stopping for some reason.

Comment: "for some reason". That's what you need to figure out and prevent from happening.

Comment: Yes, and what is the reason? What do the windows event logs show? Anything in a profile trace? If all you know is "some reason", do you really know?

Comment: @Alexander SQL Server doesn't stop by itself after a while. "is stopping for some reason" is what you should investigate and solve. Did it run out of space? Did some user shut down the service? Have you set the service to *restart* after it's shut down at least?

Comment: I was trying to avoid mentioning the restart after shutdown option... That is *not* the solution here... It will simply mask the problem and users will probably still lose data when the service dies. :)

Comment: What is in the error log? In the last lines of error log server writes why it was shutting down (if it evere has a possibility to write it)

Comment: Guys,I am so sorry.Today I went to the client firm and the problem was that they somehow plugged out the LAN cable, and that is why it wasn't working..I assumed that the web service stopped, because it happend one time a long time ago.Sorry again!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're just dealing with default behavior for user instances. Databases will auto close and engine auto shuts down after x minutes. You can extend this by changing the configuration option "user instance timeout". Details can be found at [User Instances for Non-Administrators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx) Look for the administration section with detailed scripts for showing and changing the configuration option. You should also check out [Lifetime of a User Instance Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sql-server-express-user-instances#lifetime-of-a-user-instance-connection) for more details.

This was originally intended to conserve resources that are typically scarce for SQL Express usage scenarios. Quite a bit has changed since the time this was designed. Also, with [Developer edition download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) being free now, you should seriously evaluate your use of Express to see if Developer edition is the better solution for you. Even if it's purely for local use (within your machine) for dev/test purposes, if it will eventually be deployed to a SQL Server in production, you really should use Developer edition instead of Express. If you'll only even run in Express then go ahead and make the tweaks in the paragraph above.